# topshelf windows service is not restarted after failure

Tags: windows-services, topshelf

I have created a Windows Service using Topshelf, this is my configuration:

```
HostFactory.Run(serviceConfig =>
{
    serviceConfig.Service<ServiceScheduler>(serviceInstance =>
    {
        serviceInstance.ConstructUsing(() => new ServiceScheduler());
        serviceInstance.WhenStarted((execute, hostControl) => execute.Start(hostControl));
    });

    serviceConfig.EnableServiceRecovery(recoveryOption =>
    {
        /* recoveryOption.OnCrashOnly();    // restart the service only after crash */
        recoveryOption.RestartService(1);   // first failure
        recoveryOption.RestartService(5);   // second failure
        recoveryOption.RestartService(5);   // third failure
    });
}
serviceConfig.StartAutomatically();
```

Note that I am not using: `recoveryOption.OnCrashOnly()`

My Service is a Timer based service and the following event handler is called every 30 seconds.

```
// this event handler is called every 30 seconds
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // I throw an exception from inside this method
        _syncer.DoSync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogConfig.Logger.Fatal(ex);
        _hostControl.Stop(); 
    }
}
```

This stops the service, but the service does not restart after 1 min. Not sure why?

*Note: I have not rebooted the PC after installing the service, not sure if that's needed?*

Comment: Are you throwing the exception in `Start`? Because that isn't how it works, the service needs to start, and then crash.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPatterson, I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my mistake, I had to stop the service with a non-zero exit code:

```
// this event handler is called every 30 seconds
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // exception is thrown from inside this function
        _syncer.DoSync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogConfig.Logger.Fatal(ex);
        // kill the service with a non-zero exit code, so it would be restarted
        _hostControl.Stop(TopshelfExitCode.UnhandledServiceException);  
    }
}
```